# How to fix undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.push')

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am working on  project and switched to react navigation, I did everythink same as it shown on this youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQVCkqvU1uE&t=307s

But I somehow still get an error.

Anyone knows why?

route.js:

[image]

Login.js, where the button to navigate is:

[image]

[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: Could you edit this question to contain the error that you're getting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GabrielDonadelDall'Agnol here you go, I added an error

Answer (score 1):

In the third picture, there is a typo: `navigation.push("SingUp)`. It should be `navigation.push("SignUp")`.

Comment: It is ("SignUp"), you must have missed second ".